# Pinging an IP to receive a ping

Tags: java, networking, ip, ping

I need to make a program that sends a ping, or some information like a string "check" to all IP addresses on the network, and get info back from that IP if a certain client is active. I want to receive something that tells my client that the other client is working and operating normally. I'm also not sure on how to send information to all network locations without sending a ping to a location that doesn't exist. Also, how can I find out what IP is sending that information my main client? For example, I want to send "check" from my main client to all locations on the network, and if there are computers on the network with my other client, it will receive "check" and send "ok" with their IP. This is for a school project, and my teacher is really confusing me. Nothing I tried so far is working at all.

Comment: Show us what u tried and what u want more specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either u can use Socket programming in java or can use jpcap library for sending packets.
Jpcap sample code to send packet.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

import jpcap.*;
import jpcap.packet.EthernetPacket;
import jpcap.packet.IPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.TCPPacket;

class SendTCP
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
if(args.length<1){
System.out.println(“Usage: java SentTCP <device index (e.g., 0, 1..)>”);
for(int i=0;i<devices.length;i++)
System.out.println(i+”:”+devices[i].name+”(“+devices[i].description+”)”);
System.exit(0);
}
int index=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
JpcapSender sender=JpcapSender.openDevice(devices[index]);

TCPPacket p=new TCPPacket(12,34,56,78,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,10,10);
p.setIPv4Parameter(0,false,false,false,0,false, false,false,0,1010101,100,IPPacket.IPPROTO_TCP,
InetAddress.getByName(“www.microsoft.com”),
InetAddress.getByName(“www.google.com”));
p.data=(“data”).getBytes();

EthernetPacket ether=new EthernetPacket();
ether.frametype=EthernetPacket.ETHERTYPE_IP;
ether.src_mac=new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)1,(byte)2,(byte)3,(byte)4,(byte)5};
ether.dst_mac=new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)6,(byte)7,(byte)8,(byte)9,(byte)10};
p.datalink=ether;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
sender.sendPacket(p);
}
}
```

Sample program to receive packet.

```
import jpcap.*;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;

class Tcpdump implements PacketReceiver {
public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {
System.out.println(packet);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
if(args.length<1){
System.out.println(“usage: java Tcpdump <select a number from the following>”);

for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
System.out.println(i+” :”+devices[i].name + “(” + devices[i].description+”)”);
System.out.println(” data link:”+devices[i].datalink_name + “(”
+ devices[i].datalink_description+”)”);
System.out.print(” MAC address:”);
for (byte b : devices[i].mac_address)
System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b&0xff) + “:”);
System.out.println();
for (NetworkInterfaceAddress a : devices[i].addresses)
System.out.println(” address:”+a.address + ” ” + a.subnet + ” ”
+ a.broadcast);
}
}else{
JpcapCaptor jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[Integer.parseInt(args[0])], 2000, false, 20);

jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new Tcpdump());
}
}
}
```

Reference taken from this [link](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/29/develop-a-network-packet-sendingcapturing-tool-in-java-using-jpcap/)

Comment: Alright, I'll have to study this a while and play around with it, thanks a lot.